# Compare two files in linux and output the result in one of the files

Tags: unix, terminal, grep

I have two files

file1.txt

```
  a
  b
  c
```

file2.txt

```
  a
  b
  c
  d
```

Now using grep command

```
grep -vf file1.txt file2.txt
```

will give me output as ->

```
d
```

But using this I can't save this result in any one of files `file1` or `file2`. I want to simply overwrite this result in any one of the files.
How can this be done using grep?

Comment: You are looking for the append operator within linux. '>' or '>>'. [Here is an answer showing how to string a grep command into a file append/overwrite.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396622/how-to-a-grep-a-word-from-a-file-and-store-it-into-another-existing-file)

Answer (score 0):

> But using this I cant save this result in any one of files file1 or
> file2. I want to simply overwrite this result in any one of the files.
> How can this be done using grep

you can redirect the output to a file like this:

```
grep -vf file1.txt file2.txt > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file1.txt
```

Notice that with grep you cannot use the same input file as output file. To solve this you create a temporary file and then rename it to file1(2).txt